# Python: Parsing SGML

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, sgml

I'm trying to parse some SGML like the following in Python:

```
<!DOCTYPE lewis SYSTEM "lewis.dtd">
<TEXT>
    <TITLE>One</TITLE>
    <BODY>Sample One</BODY>
</TEXT>
<TEXT>
    <TITLE>Two</TITLE>
    <BODY>Sample Two</BODY>
</TEXT>
```

Here, I'm just looking for everything inside the `<BODY>` tags (i.e. `["Sample One", "Sample Two"]`).

I've tried using BeautifulSoup, but it doesn't like the `<!DOCTYPE>` in the first line and also expects everything to be wrapped around a root tag like `<everything></everything>`. While I can manually make these changes before passing it into BeautifulSoup, it feels a bit too hacky.

I'm pretty new to SGML, and also not married to BeautifulSoup, so I'm open to any suggestions.

(For those curious: my specific usecase is the reuters21578 dataset.)

Comment: What parser are you using with beautiful soup ?

Comment: I'm using "lxml-xml", as recommended in one of the docs.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `'html.parser'` as the parser instead of `lxml-xml`. `lxml-xml` would expect the text to be correct xml , which is not the case.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<!DOCTYPE lewis SYSTEM "lewis.dtd">
... <TEXT>
...     <TITLE>One</TITLE>
...     <BODY>Sample One</BODY>
... </TEXT>
... <TEXT>
...     <TITLE>Two</TITLE>
...     <BODY>Sample Two</BODY>
... </TEXT>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('body')
[<body>Sample One</body>, <body>Sample Two</body>]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the only way to make this valid XML to strip out the first line and wrap everything in a dummy root element? I'm interested in using lxml primarily for performance reasons (also, is there no standard SGML parser)?

Comment: I do not think BeautifulSoup inbuilt has sgml parser, `'lxml'` may also work for you , that is `lxml html` parser (not the xml version) . More on the parsers supported - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser